# modelling node explorations using google OR tools, with constraint

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

I have a problem with this kind of outline.

Given nodes A, B, C, D, etc with directed edges. calculate the path best path that satisfy the constraint.

constraint:
Edges is directed and each pair has multiple edges
each edge has multiple parameter such as, height and distance
Nodes can be visited multiple times.

Target: Get the path that visit the most nodes, while minimizing distance, while the total height is limited

for a simple example with 2 nodes

```
nodes: A B
edges: A->B height:7, distance:7 #edge 1
       A->B height:10, distance:10 #edge 2
       B->A height:8, distance:8 #edge 3
       B->A height:10, distance:10 #edge 4
maximum height = 25
the result should be A->B->A
with edge 1, edge 3, edge 1
total_height: 7+8+7
score: distance_max/ total_nodes_visited = max(7,8,7) = 3/7
```

I took a look at the sample from or tools' python, but I am not sure which one to take. I wanted to make it as a circuit, but I am not sure how to write it to enable visiting multiple nodes

I hope I explained the problem correctly.
Any help or direction is appreciated!